# PrimeFaces dinamic CommandButtons and ContextMenu

Tags: java, primefaces, contextmenu

Please help me to solve the issue/question on how to add a dynamic `ContextMenu`(on left click) for `CommandButtons` which are dynamically added via Java. The count of CommandButtons is dynamic(min 50), but the `ContextMenu` is always the same:

```
Column column = ...
ContextMenu contextmenu = ...

CommandButton button1 = new CommandButton();
//todo addContextMenu
CommandButton button2 = new CommandButton();
//todo addContextMenu
...
CommandButton button50 = new CommandButton();
//todo addContextMenu

column.getChildren().add(button1);
column.getChildren().add(button2);
...
column.getChildren().add(button50);
```

PS I use Primefaces 5.3, Primefaces Extensions 4.0, Mojarra 2.2.5. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you know that `Primefaces` give you the `contextMenu` component  ?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CommandButtons activate their action with a left click, so you might look for MenuButtons, which have a menu triggered by left click and an arrow, that shows the availability of a dynamic Menu.

The programmtic creation of menues is described in the Primefaces Menu-showcase under the tab *MenuView.java*.